# Common Header and Footer for ASP.Net MVC and WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have an application written in ASP.Net Webforms. But we are trying to develop all new reports in MVC. We have created a sample POC where we can navigate to aspx as well as cshtml depending on the page extension. It works fine. But I wanted to know if I can use same header and footer for both types of pages. As the MVC Views load inside _Layout.cshtml and aspx pages do not. I also want to maintain the exact same look and feel for headers and footers as the user should not see any difference and redirects should be smooth. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to get them to look the same. aspx will use master pages while MVC uses the _Layout. You would however be maintaining multiple pages though. Try to extract the most common aspects into one file that you can reference from both implementations. It will help reduce duplicate work.

Comment: What components can be extracted? are you saying styles in css?